# Deadlock occurs when transferring data from one database to another database

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

- We have two databases, let's say DataBase A and DataBase B.
- DataBase A is accessed 24 X 7 by the robots.
- We need to transfer data of two tables from DataBase A to DataBase B, using "insert into select" query.
- But after executing the query, a deadlock occurs, because DataBase A is being accessed.

So what will be the best possible ways to transfer the data from DataBase A to DataBase B without deadlock.

In addition, if we already know that deadlock will occur on firing the script, can we set **more priority** to **"executing the query" than the "database access by  robots"**?

What will be the possible ways to **set robots as a deadlock victim and not the query** ?

Comment: You should post the deadlock graph

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. Database A is getting deadlocked even though your process is just reading from database A?

Comment: `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW`